# Python NameError: name 'harris' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I apologize in advance if there is somewhere the same thread of mine. 
I am new in Python programming and trying to compute an example from "**Programming Computer Vision with Python**" written by **Jan Erik Solem**.

Here is the code of the example (saved in a file called "harris.py"):

https://github.com/jesolem/PCV/blob/master/pcv_book/harris.py

(Be aware that my code ends at line 70)

After a good explanation of this code, in the book is stated: "Try running the following commands:"

```
im = array(Image.open(’empire.jpg’).convert(’L’))
harrisim = harris.compute_harris_response(im)
filtered_coords = harris.get_harris_points(harrisim,6)
harris.plot_harris_points(im, filtered_coords)
```

The problems I've encountered are two:

1. I am not sure where to run those last lines of code, in harris.py
   or in a separate python file.
2. In whichever file I run it, the following error is shown:

   `harrisim = harris.compute_harris_response(im)`
   `NameError: name 'harris' is not defined`

I don't understand why this error is shown, since 'harris' should call the python script harris.py. Or am I wrong?

Comment: name harris will call harris, if you have imported harris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is meant to go into a separate file, but you need to *import* the `harris` module first:

```
import harris
```

before the module is available to your code.

Comment: If I write just:
`import harris`
there is another error:
`ImportError: No module named harris`
Sorry again if my questions seem to be too stupid, but it's my first time programming in python.

Comment: @FrancescoSgaramella: that means the directory where `harris.py` is located is not part of your module search path. When running the interpreter interactively, the *current directory* is automatically added to the search path, when running a script with `python path/to/script.py` then the directory the script lives in is added.

Comment: @FrancescoSgaramella: In other words, run `python` in the same directory as your `harris.py` file.

Comment: I moved harris.py into my Python path and now works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Harris name does not exists in your script (it was not initialised at any time before using it, so Python does not know what harris is). If `import harris` does not work, it is because the fact that you do not have any module called that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully of the initial part of his book. He wrote "add the functions in the harris.py file" in the beginning of this chapter. You should follow his step exactly.